# How can I fix Java errors after upgrading to C++Builder Alexandria (Windows 10)?

Tags: java, c++builder-11-alexandria

Running C++Builder 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236 Community Edition under Windows 10.

Since updating my Community Edition of C++Builder, when I try to debug an app on my phone, I get loads of Java errors, but didn't even know Java was part of it.

How do I find out what's gone wrong?

I've noticed that a file mentioned in the first error (see below), "dex_list.txt", seems to contain the paths of several files, of which the following do not exist:

- android-support-v4.dex.jar
- apk-expansion.dex.jar
- cloud-messaging.dex.jar
- google-analytics-v2.dex.jar
- google-play-billing.dex.jar
- google-play-services.dex.jar

The errors start with:

```
paclient command line
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --dexmerge="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe,c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.3.28.jar,C:\My C++ Source Code\Android\ToDoList\Android\Debug\ToDoList.classes,23,C:\My C++ Source 
  Code\Android\ToDoList\Android\Debug\dex_list.txt"
  
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Unable to execute '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" -cp "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.3.28.jar" com.android.tools.r8.D8 --release --min-api 23 --output "C:\My C++ Source Code\Android\ToDoList\Android\Debug\ToDoList.classes" @"C:\My C++ Source Code\Android\ToDoList\Android\Debug\dex_list.txt"' (Error 1)

[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Error in c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar:

[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar

[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Error in c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\apk-expansion.dex.jar:

[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\apk-expansion.dex.jar
```

Comment: You are trying to debug what application (it is a c, c++, Java, Swift, Kotlin, etc project?) in what kind of phone (I guess Android but you should say it. It isn't iOS right?)? If it is Android, is the project pure C++? You should provide more details.

Comment: Presumably Android, since it is running Java on top of Linux

Comment: And some of the jars are named after Android and Google services for Android.  But that should be provided up front in the question

Comment: Managed to fix this by the following :

1/. In Rad Studio, in the Project WIndow, right clicked on Project / Target Platforms (Android 32 bit) / Android SDK 25.2.5 32-bit / Libraries, then in the menu that pops up, click on Revert System Files to Default

2/. Uninstall the app from the phone, reboot the phone then debug the app as usual